# How to fix: Use of unassigned local IWebElement variable

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For the following code,

```
IWebElement element; // = new WebElement();
try
{
    element = driver.FindElement(By...);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
element.Click();
```

How to fix the error of `Use of unassigned local variable`?

I know for the error of `Use of unassigned local variable`, the fix is to assign it with something initially, but I've tried `new WebElement();` and `new IWebElement();` but they didn't work for me.

Any help?

PS. I was trying in the `catch` statement to loop and find it, that's why I need the element declaration outside of `try`, and `Click()` after it.

Comment: You shouldn't click the element if you cannot find the element, so put `element.Click()` in the `try` block after `element = ...`.

Comment: I was trying in the `catch` statement to loop and find it, that's why I need the element declaration outside of `try`, and `Click()` after it.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that it's possible that, after the `catch` completes, that `element` is not assigned. You can assign it to `null` (or `default(IWebElement)`) when you declare it to get rid of the error, then check for `null` before calling `Click()`.

Comment: Then you need to find a way to ensure that you find the element (which is not a good thing to do IMHO - the element may not always be there).

Comment: `IWebElemnt element = null;` or move the `element.Click()` into the `try`

Comment: Thanks, Rufus & Tim. I'll assign it to `null` when declaring it and see how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: @xpt It sounds like you're wanting to loop to find it... why not use `WebDriverWait`? That's what it's designed for. Then you don't have to re-invent the wheel with a messy try catch loop disaster :)

Comment: Oh thanks @mrfreester, that is _indeed_ something that I was about to search for :-).

Comment: @AleksAndreev, Have you noticed in my OP, "_I know for the error of Use of unassigned local variable, the fix is to assign it with something initially_"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler helps to fix a bug. He's telling you that this will fail with a `NullReferenceException`at `element.Click()` if there was an exception during initialization of `element`. So he wants you to assign something in any case(or as default value). You have multiple options to fix...

Use the object after the initialization in the `try`:

```
try
{
    element = driver.FindElement(By...);
    element.Click();  // safe because there was no exception
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // empty catch is bad, log this at least
}
```

"Hide" the compiler error but let the potential bug live by assigning something to the variable:

```
IWebElement element = null;
try
{
    element = driver.FindElement(By...);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // empty catch is bad, log this at least
}

element.Click(); // still a bug if there was an exception this will cause a NullReferenceException
```

this option is perfectly fine if you use `if(element != null) element.Click();` instead.

Or you could use the `catch`/`finally` to assign something (imo worst option here):

```
IWebElement element;
try
{
    element = driver.FindElement(By...);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    element = null;
}
```

But then you have to check for `null`, either with `if(element != null)` or with:

```
element?.Click(); // if not null Click is called
```